# Trying to read an MS Office Document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop

I have a chunk of code that I'm using to read MS Office Word documents.

```
static void ReadMSOfficeWordFile(string file) {
    try {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application msWordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object ofalse = false;
        object ofile = file;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = msWordApp.Documents.Open(
                                                    ref ofile, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                    ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                    ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                    ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                    ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                    ref nullobj);
        string result = doc.Content.Text.Trim();
        doc.Close(ref ofalse, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
        msWordApp.Quit();
        CheckLineMatch(file, result);
    }
    catch {
        RaiseError("Unable to parse file because of MS Office error.", file);
    }
}
```

I have three issues with this.

First- It relies on MS Office being installed on each system this might run on. Some people prefer Libre Office, but this still needs to run against MS Office Word documents.

Second- I don't know if this will even work for MS Office 2003 AND MS Office 2007 documents...

Third- It's SLOW. It's excruciatingly slow.

SO! I assume there MUST be a better way to run it than this. I'm guessing that someone has to know of a better way than what a novice is coming with. I'm only trying to read the text in the document, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your "Word application hanging open", you need to tell it to close.

```
msWordApp.Quit()
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb215475(v=office.12).aspx

Regarding the "relies on MS Offise being installed", you are using the interop. So by definition is requires it to be installed. You can look into one of the commercial libraries.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx
http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/pricelist

Comment: Thanks! That indeed fixes that part.

Comment: Instead we can use NPOI, this is open source project. See my post down for a sample how to use NPOI to read all text from a .DOC file

Answer (score 4):

We are able to achieve a lot of thing with [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/), an open source project, without any office dependability.

for an e.g. Reading all text from a word document can implement a shown below.

```
public string ReadAllTextFromWordDocFile(string fileName)
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        var document = new HWPFDocument(streamReader.BaseStream);
        var wordExtractor = new WordExtractor(document);
        var docText = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string text in wordExtractor.ParagraphText)
        {
            docText.AppendLine(text.Trim());
        }
        streamReader.Close();
        return docText.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Office Interop is an option (slow as you already discovered) but beware: it is **not supported** by MS in server-like scenarios (like ASP.NET or Windows Service or similar) - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2 !*

Usually some library is used to achieve what you want:

- [MS provides the OpenXML SDK V 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx) (free, supports only DOCX)
- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial, supports DOC and DOCX)

The library approach is usually very fast, usable with multi-threading, usable in server-scenarios and comes with lots of additional possibilities...

As for your *Second* point: with Interop you need to call [`Quit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationclass.quit%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to close the application... although sometimes you need to call `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` too (which can have some undesired side-effects see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvesdolc/archive/2004/04/17/115379.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this project from CodePlex - [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/)

From the website, here are some key features:

- Office integration without version limitations
- All methods, properties and events of the Office versions 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010 are included
- Syntactically and semantically identical to the Microsoft Interop Assemblies

Comment: NetOffice seems to still require Office to be installed.