# How to parse text from MS Word document to string

Tags: c#, parsing, text, ms-word

I am trying to find a way to parse a word document's text to a string in my project.I have more than 600 word(.doc) files that I need to get the text content(with the new lines and tabs if possible) and assign it to a string for each one.

I've been reading stuff about the Open XML SDK but it looks quite complicated for something that looks so simple.

Comment: `.doc` or `.docx`? `.doc` is MS Word 2003 format and earlier - I don't believe they are XML documents like `.docx`

Comment: all of the files are in .doc format

Answer (score 5):

Open XML SDK is only for 2007 and newer formats and it is not trivial to use.

If performance is not an issue you could use Word Automation and have Word do this for you. 
It will look something like this:

```
var app = new Application();
var doc = app.Documents.Open(documentLocation);

string rangeText = doc.Range().Text;

doc.Save();
doc.Close();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);    
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18703/Word-2007-Automation or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21247/Word-Automation for more complete examples and instructions. Note that this may become a bit more tricky if your documents are move complex (footnotes, text boxes, tables...).

Another option is have word save the document as a text and then read the text file. Take a look at this - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could give a look at [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/):

> This project is the .NET version of POI Java project at
>   http://poi.apache.org/. POI is an open source project which can help
>   you read/write xls, doc, ppt files. It has a wide application.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672461/trying-to-read-an-ms-office-document) previous SO thread for more information.

Comment: How do I exactly reference that project in my Solution ?

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: You usually download the required DLL files and include them in your references. Alternatively, you can get an addon for visual studio (NuGet) to do it for you, assuming that these DLL's are in its repositories.

Comment: I don't really kno which ones to pick and how to use them later(Instatiate classes, using their methods and so on).

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: Usually you just download the DLL's and create a reference from your project. This will in turn make visual studio import the code specified in your DLL's, so you can use it. You should be able to find plenty of tutorials online on how to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I know the way it is supposed to be done but I was talking particularly about this NPOI project on the GitHub.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: I have just downloaded the Beta version and it seems that besides the DLL's, there are also some examples to get you started. If you are still having issues with this, then I recommend you contact the people at NPOI.