# C# - Read plain text from XML data containing Word fields

Tags: c#, xml, cpu-word

I am developing a 'Search' feature for an application wherein I search for a keyword within XML content. I need to search only for the plain text i.e no xml tags or word fields. Below is a snippet of the code I use to read the text (excluding the XML tags and binary data):

```
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(strXmlContent));

  while (reader.Read())
  {
      if (reader.Name == "pkg:binaryData" || reader.Name == "w:binData")
      {
           reader.Skip();
      }
      if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
      {
           result.Append(reader.Value);
      }
  }

  //Plain text without XML tags.
  string plainText = result.ToString();

  if (txt.ToLower().Contains(SearchText.ToLower()))
  {
       // display search results
  }
```

However, I found that since this xml actually stores Word document content, it also contains Word fields such as : ( REF _Ref325306498 \h * MERGEFORMAT Figure 1 and REF _Ref325306499 \h * MERGEFORMAT Figure 2)

Here the content that I want to search is "(Figure 1 and Figure 2)".
But I am unable to find this text as it also contains MERGEFORMAT and other Word fields.

How can I read only plain text from this xml data?

Answer (score 0):

After parsing each XML DOM element containing a Word file, you could parse the word document into a string and then use that for your search - there are a couple of ways provided to get the word document contents as a string in this [other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676712/how-to-parse-text-from-ms-word-document-to-string) - essentially, you could either save the document as text using Word automation or use a third party library or use the Word DOM from within your code.

Comment: Anand, thanks for replying. This did help a little. But when I tried to Load the the word document with xml content, I got an OutOfMemoryException since we are looping though numerous database records here (The xmlContent comes from the database).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with XElement and XPath. You need to add System.Xml.Linq and System.Xml.XPath namespaces in your using directives.

```
var xml = XElement.Load("filepath");
string searchText="your search text";
var matchElements=xml.XPathSelectElements(@"//*[contains(.,'"+searchText+"')]");
```