# Parse Word (.doc /.docx) document

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

Is there a way/best possible solution to parse a .doc / .docx in c#/asp.net?

My document look like this:

```
(repeater)

chapter(text)

picture

text

(/repeater)
```

It is very important that the parser readers the picture.

Comment: The DOC format is not supported.  Microsoft has documented it, but only just enough to say they did (they did it as a good faith exercise while they were being sued by the US Department of Justice).  The format is insane (it relies on COM's "storage and stream" technology).  You will be much happier supporting only the DOCX format and using a widely available tool like OpenXML SDK or EPPlus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the following question you can find a general word doc parsing: [How to parse text from MS Word document to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676712/how-to-parse-text-from-ms-word-document-to-string) 
and in this MSDN page you can find how to handle pictures in the document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh965732(v=office.14).aspx

post your code example if you need a specific help.

Comment: plus 1 for been President Camacho

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately that supports only .doc not .docx format.

Comment: OpenXML SDK supports only .docx