# c# Novacode.Picture to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, type-conversion, openxml, novacode-docx

I'm reading in a .docx file using the Novacode API, and am unable to create or display any images within the file to a WinForm app due to not being able to convert from a Novacode Picture (pic) or Image to a system image. I've noticed that there's very little info inside the pic itself, with no way to get any pixel data that I can see. So I have been unable to utilize any of the usual conversion ideas.

I've also looked up how Word saves images inside the files as well as Novacode source for any hints and I've come up with nothing.

My question then is is there a way to convert a Novacode Picture to a system one, or should I use something different to gather the image data like OpenXML? If so, would Novacode and OpenXML conflict in any way?

There's also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769501/6674014) that might be another place to start.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about novacode, but maybe as another idea, you could extract the image in another way? i.e. If you were to change a .docx extension to a .docx.zip extension and then open as a zip file, you can navigate to /word/media and find the images here.

Comment: When I do this it lists all the images with generic names like "image1.png" and so forth. Same as in Novacode. I've looked inside the .docx to see if I could manually name images but couldn't find anything. Is there any tag inside .pngs that keeps the original file name?

Comment: I guess I am going through them in order, so this could work as long as they are indeed named that way. Still seems like a very roundabout way of doing things though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. This is what I ended up doing. Thanks to [gattsbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1684720/gattsbr) for the advice. This only works if you can grab all the images in order, and have descending names for all the images.

```
using System.IO.Compression; // Had to add an assembly for this
using Novacode;

// Have to specify to remove ambiguous error from Novacode
Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image> images = new Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image>();

void LoadTree()
{
    // In case of previous exception
    if(File.Exists("Images.zip")) { File.Delete("Images.zip"); }

    // Allow the file to be open while parsing
    using(FileStream stream = File.Open("Images.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using(DocX doc = DocX.Load(stream))
        {
            // Work rest of document

            // Still parse here to get the names of the images
            // Might have to drag and drop images into the file, rather than insert through Word
            foreach(Picture pic in doc.Pictures)
            {
                string name = pic.Description;

                if(null == name) { continue; }

                name = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - 4);

                images[name] = null;
            }

            // Save while still open
            doc.SaveAs("Images.zip");
        }
    }

    // Use temp zip directory to extract images
    using(ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.OpenRead("Images.zip"))
    {
        // Gather all image names, in order
        // They're retrieved from the bottom up, so reverse
        string[] keys = images.Keys.OrderByDescending(o => o).Reverse().ToArray();

        for(int i = 1; ; i++)
        {
            // Also had to add an assembly for ZipArchiveEntry
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.GetEntry(String.Format("word/media/image{0}.png", i));

            if(null == entry) { break; }

            Stream stream = entry.Open();

            images[keys[i - 1]] = new Bitmap(stream);
        }
    }

    // Remove temp directory
    File.Delete("Images.zip");
}
```